# Почему цикл for выводит каждую итерацию, а не сумму успешных проверок?

Tags: javascript

Цикл должен выдавать в console.log количество четных делителей числа 6. Проблема заключается в том что цикл выдает именно четные делители числа 6 а не их количество. То есть на данный момент цикл выдает числа (2 и 6) а должен выдавать их количество **2**

```js
const numberTenthTask = 6;
for (let i = 1; i <= numberTenthTask; i++) {
    if (numberTenthTask % i === 0 && i % 2 === 0) {
        console.log(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы выводите номер успешной итерации, а надо суммировать количество успешных проверок и уже потом выводить результат

```js
const numberTenthTask = 6;
let count = 0;
for (let i = 1; i <= numberTenthTask; i++) {
    if (numberTenthTask % i === 0 && i % 2 === 0) {
        count++;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```